# How to reinstall php70-xdebug with the debug symbols?

Tags: homebrew, php

I'd like to reinstall `php70-xdebug` package with debug symbols like:

```
$ brew reinstall php70-xdebug --with-debug
==> Reinstalling homebrew/php/php70-xdebug 
Warning: homebrew/php/php70-xdebug: this formula has no --with-debug option so it will be ignored!
```

however there is no `--with-debug` or other similar option to use (which does exist for `php70`).

How can I recompile this package with debug symbols via `brew`?

Comment: Related: [Cannot load Xdebug, as PHP was built with API NTS debug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41895038/55075).

Answer (score 1):

If the debugging option is not available for `php70-xdebug` (they aren't at the time of writing), you can add it by using one of the methods suggested below.

#### Manual steps

The debug options can be added manually by the following steps:

1. Edit formula by this shell command:

   ```
   brew edit php70-xdebug
   ```
2. Add the following lines:

   ```
   option "enable-debug", "Compile with debugging symbols"
   option "disable-debug", "Compile without debugging symbols (default)"
   ```
3. Verify the existence of option by:

   ```
   brew options php70-xdebug
   ```
4. Reinstall package by:

   ```
   brew reinstall php70-xdebug --build-from-source --enable-debug
   ```

#### Pulling the changes from fork

Pull the changes from [pull request #4341](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/pull/4341) from GitHub by:

```
cd "$(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-php"
git pull https://github.com/kenorb-contrib/homebrew-php.git task/php70-xdebug-debug-options
brew reinstall php70-xdebug --build-from-source --enable-debug
```

---

Related: [Cannot load Xdebug, as PHP was built with API NTS debug](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41895038/55075).